# Google map crashed when app is offline in Phonegap

Tags: android, html, google-maps, cordova

I am in a project which is integrated with google map by Phonegap.

When the data connection is not there, getting an error page in the browser like 'web page is not available' as below.

[image]

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to check connectivity and if its data connected, after that you can make a map call. also you can't make any cross domain request at offline

sample

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

Please refer the phonegap document more option
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection